# Can't build Cordova project with the newest Visual Studio CTP

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I've updated my Visual Studio to CTP 6. After that I can't build my project. Every time I get following error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       EBUSY, resource busy or locked '<PATH_TO_PROJECT>\.vs\<PROJECT_NAME>\v14\vbcs.cache\edb.log'    <PROJECT_NAME> <PATH_TO_PROJECT>\MDAVSCLI   1
```

It happens regardless of platform (I've tried Android, iOS and Windows Phone). I tried to check with Process Explorer if some other app is blocking this file but only devenv process is using it.

One thing I've changed in the project after updating is

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets" />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.TypeScript.MDA.targets" />
```

to

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets" />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.TypeScript.MDA.targets" />
```

in the jsproj file, but I don't think that's important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issues (but a different error message), with an Android NDK project. It looks like there are project breaking changes between CTP5 and CTP6. The way I fixed it was to create a new project (with the same name, but a different location) from the wizard and verified that it built. I then used beyond compare ([link](http://www.scootersoftware.com)) to compare the contents of the two projects and copy the non-default lines in project.sln, project.Packaging.androidproj, project.vcxproj, project.vcxproj.filters, etc.,  from my old project to my new project. Your project is a different kind, so the relevant files may be somewhat different for you.

Comment: I've tried before the opposite way to yours, copy the default lines from the new one to the old one. It didn't work. Your approach works, but I did it from the VS. I don't know why I haven't tried that before ;)

Anyway, based on the diff file from the jsproj file, here are the difference:
1. ProjectId's changed from `84f95632-f55a-4ce2-bca4-f2218b0dd218` to `afebb072-5a30-43d5-9836-5106c302ffba`,
2. `<Service Include="{4a0dddb5-7a95-4fbf-97cc-616d07737a77}" />` line was added,
3. TypeScriptToolsVersion has changed (in my case from 1.0 to 1.4)
4. The lines mentioned in the first post

Thanks!